# How to change the price format (RSD format) in ionic 3?

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, currency

At the moment, the price is shown like **12,000.00**

But, I want it to display in the format of **12.000,00**

Code written by me:

```
<h1 class="title" (click)="movedetail($event)">{{tms.price | number:'1.2-2'}}</h1>
```

Any suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: You may have to create a custom pipe to achieve this.

Comment: if you change the default locale of your application to the locale which uses 12.000,00 format, all numbers will formatted automatically, alternatively you can pass locale in the number pipe like this, number:'1.2-2':'es'. You will need to register the locale before using it. see https://angular.io/guide/i18n